# R Shiny delay in updating textInput values

Tags: r, shiny

Below is a simple R Shiny app example with textInput and actionButton, after clicking the button it is supposed to set the text value to NULL and print NULL value, however I have observed that after clicking the submit button it still prints the value entered in the textInput. Can anyone please explain why there is this delay in updating the textInput value ?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    textInput("text", "Test"),
    actionButton("Submit","Submit")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$Submit,{
      updateTextInput(session,"text", value = " ")
      print(input$text)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

After running the app if I enter "hello" in the text input, I should get " " on the print console, but it shows the value of input$text , i.e "hello" in the print console. Clearly the assignment of " " is not happening in the sequence it is written in the code.

Please share if anyone can explain this behavior in Shiny app.
Thank you for your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this behaviour is that updateTextInput (and all update*Input functions for that matter) does not update the `input` object in the server function. Instead, it sends a message to the client (the browser) to change the text input field. And when the text input field in the browser is updated, the browser sends back a signal to the server that `input$text` has been changed. But before that happens, the execution of code inside the `observeEvent` block has continued, and so when executing `print(input$text)`, the value is still "hello".

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bobbel, this explains the behavior of update input functions and makes sense. However, is it possible to update the text value on the server which will in turn show up in the browser, so that the print statement in the next lines shows the updated value from the server.

Comment: It depends a bit on how complex your real application is. One solution could be to store the information to be printed in a `reactiveValues` object ([documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.11/reactiveValues.html)) instead of using `input`.